# AmCharts4: Datagrouping, Tooltiptext and changing ranges

Tags: amcharts4

From a server, I get an entry for every hour in the range I request. If I request a range of 1 Year, I get something like 8000 Datapoints.

When rendering the graph, I want to group my data to hours(which is the raw data without grouping), days and months. However, the chart looks like this:
[image]

The tooltip does only display on the very first column, all other columns are above 1.5, but my ValueAxis does not scale automatically. I already checked if I set fixed min and max for the valueAxis, this is not the case.

Interestingly, if i use the scrollbar to zoom in until grouping kicks in, everything seems to work:

[image]

After zooming out again, it also works, but i cannot see the tooltip on the "June-Column":
[image]

And finally, if I trigger "invalidateData" the graph goes back to the state it was before.

My grouping looks as follows:

```
series = entry.chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
dateAxis.groupData = true;
dateAxis.groupCount = 40;
dateAxis.groupIntervals.setAll([
     { timeUnit: "hour", count: 1 },
     { timeUnit: "day", count: 1 },
     { timeUnit: "month", count: 1 },
     { timeUnit: "year", count: 1 },
     { timeUnit: "year", count: 10 }
]);
series.groupFields.valueY = "sum";
```

I am also not very sure what I should set those values to. I want to see:

- months when there is a period of 3 months or more
- days when there is a period of 3 days until 3 months
- hours when there is a period below 3 days

It is very difficult to do a fiddle for this, as there already is so much code and its hard to extract only the essential parts.

Maybe I am missing something obvious, please help!

Edit:

I forgot another question which is part of datagrouping:
How can I make the tooltip to show the date in a formatted matter so that:

- hour-columns shows "dd hh:mm"(where mm obviously is 00 all the time)
- day-columns shows: "dd.mm"
- month-columns shows: "MM. YYYY"

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I solved this issue. This was actually a bug fixed in this release:
https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/releases/tag/4.7.19

so updating my local amCharts4 files did the trick.

I still do not know how to change the tooltiptext and the grouping as described in my question